# Converting a multi column dataframe to a two column dataframe

Tags: r

How do I convert a multi column dataframe to a two column dataframe.

For example, i have a dataset with four columns

```
    foo<-data.frame(

            w= rnorm(10, mean=50, sd=10),
            x= sample(1:10, 10, replace=T),
            y=c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                "green"),
            z=runif(10, 5.0, 7.5))

      w         x      y        z
      42.67991  8    red 7.460069
      46.40567  5    red 6.159747
      65.67709  8    red 7.352203
      57.53091  4   blue 5.838025
      37.31885  1   blue 5.486540
      46.38344  5   blue 5.848174
      50.65255  1 yellow 7.434667
      45.31212  1 yellow 7.449169
      49.10322 10 yellow 6.611908
      39.10083 10  green 6.539835
```

I am trying to covert this four column dataframe to a two column dataframe (a,b) as follows

```
      a             b
      42.67991      8    
      46.40567      5    
      .             .
      .             .
      red           7.460069
      red           6.159747
      .             .
      .             .
      8             red 
      5             red
      .             .
      .             .
      42.67991      red 
      46.40567      red 
      .     .
      .             .

      42.67991      7.460069
      46.40567      6.159747
      .             .
      .             .
      8             7.460069
      5             6.159747
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Also, please explain your rules....

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am trying to create a from-to matrix, only rule is that all the dataset should be in a two column format. after the first two columns w , x the next column for example y, z should start right after w, x ends...so on.

Comment: Your sample output doesn't seem to match anything in the input...

Comment: @Bridgeport Tucker Jr If the rule is that `y, z` follows `w, x`, why do you have `red` in both columns `a` and `b`?  Another concern is that by doing this you will be having `character` columns as both `characters` and `numeric` elements get mixed up

Comment: @akrun , yes this is as per design :), duplicate observations are okay because I am mainly interested in immediate pairs so for example if the original column y appears twice under column b that is fine. Regarding numbers and characters getting mixed up I will convert the two columns a & be to character (as.character).

Comment: @BridgeportTuckerJr Thanks for the reply.  But, as Ananda Mahto mentioned, the output you showed is not matching with the input dataset.  Perhaps you can change it.

Comment: People should really be telling you...NO! The vectors in a dataframe need to be all of the same mode (that is the language design) and you are mixing numeric and character modes. Then, of course, there is the problem that there is no apparent relationship between the input and the output. For instance there is no 7 in your input and there is in the output.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I drew 10 samples from uniform and normal distribution so this changed a bit while pasting, i will fix that :)

Comment: @BondedDust I used the function sample for my example so my numbers got mixed up while creating the second output table...dang :)

Comment: Apologies in comments are not acceptable. Use the edit function to improve the question.

Comment: @BridgeportTuckerJr From the output, it appears that you want every combination of two columns.  If that is the case, I posted a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
indx <- combn(1:ncol(foo), 2)
res <-  do.call(rbind,lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(i) {
                 x1 <- foo[i]
                 colnames(x1) <- letters[1:2]
                x1}))

row.names(res) <- NULL
head(res)
#        a b
#1 42.67991 8
#2 46.40567 5
#3 65.67709 8
#4 57.53091 4
#5 37.31885 1
#6 46.38344 5
```

Or

```
res1 <-  do.call(rbind,combn(1:ncol(foo), 2, FUN= function(i) 
                       list(setNames(foo[i], letters[1:2]))))
```

#### data

```
foo <- structure(list(w = c(42.67991, 46.40567, 65.67709, 57.53091, 
37.31885, 46.38344, 50.65255, 45.31212, 49.10322, 39.10083), 
x = c(8L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L), y = c("red", 
"red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "yellow", 
"yellow", "green"), z = c(7.460069, 6.159747, 7.352203, 5.838025, 
5.48654, 5.848174, 7.434667, 7.449169, 6.611908, 6.539835
)), .Names = c("w", "x", "y", "z"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```